# How to change the sql column data type in iOS?

Tags: ios, sql, sqlite, alter

In my iOS app,I want to change the column data type in database.

```
ALTER TABLE XXX ALTER COLUMN myColumn INT.
```

I always get 'near ALTER Syntax error'
How to resolve the problem?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Which database are you using?  sqlite3?

Comment: Yes,how to fix the error?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the column type. You can create a new table, using the correct data type for the column this time, and then select data from the old table and insert it into the new table. The full procedure is outlined in the [ALTER TABLE documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html):

> 1. Remember the format of all indexes and triggers associated with table X. This information will be needed in step 7 below. One way to do this is to run a query like the following: `SELECT type, sql FROM sqlite_master WHERE tbl_name='X'`.
> 2. Use `CREATE TABLE` to construct a new table "new_X" that is in the desired revised format of table X. Make sure that the name "new_X" does not collide with any existing table name, of course.
> 3. Transfer content from X into new_X using a statement like: `INSERT INTO new_X SELECT ... FROM X`.
> 4. If foreign key constraints are enabled, disable them using `PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF`.
> 5. Drop the old table X: `DROP TABLE X`.
> 6. Change the name of new_X to X using: `ALTER TABLE new_X RENAME TO X`.
> 7. Use `CREATE INDEX` and `CREATE TRIGGER` to reconstruct indexes and triggers associated with table X. Perhaps use the old format of the triggers and indexes saved from step 1 above as a guide, making changes as appropriate for the alteration.
> 8. If foreign key constraints were originally enabled (prior to step 4) then run `PRAGMA foreign_key_check` to verify that the schema change did not break any foreign key constraints, and run `PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON` to re-enable foreign key constraints.
> 9. If any views refer to table X in a way that is affected by the schema change, then drop those views using `DROP VIEW` and recreate them with whatever changes are necessary to accommodate the schema change using `CREATE VIEW`.

Note, SQLite uses [type affinity](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity) (the column definition doesn't alter what type of data you insert into the table). So if you change the data type, you'll want to change the data, too.

Answer (score 0):

1. `ALTER TABLE table ADD newColumn INTEGER;`
2. `UPDATE table SET newColumn = oldColumn;`

Comment: Is there a direct way to get it? Like alter,modify or change in SQLite

Comment: Yes, as Rob said you cannot change the column type in SQLite. Therefore, you need to create a new field and then update old column to the new column.